# Trying to understand following code for reversing a sentence

Tags: java, collections

Please consider the code below:

```
public class SentenceReversal {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String[] parts = "This is an interview Question".split("\\b");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = parts.length; i --> 0 ;) {
            sb.append(parts[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("[" + sb.toString() + "]");

}
}
```

What does "\b" is doing in split function? Removing it is producing the following result(that means using only split("")):

`[noitseuQ weivretni na si sihT]`

Also, what does `-->' operator is doing in the for loop? I didn't quite understand. Please help me in understanding my questions.

Thanks

Comment: `i --> 0` ==> `i-- > 0`.

Comment: [Javadocs for `Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bounds) says "A word boundary"

Comment: The `i --> 0 ;` part is actually `i-- > 0`, which is the use of the unary operator `--`. It's the same as `i > 0` followed by `i = i-1`.

Comment: `i --> 0` is so deceptive, yet somehow isn't in this scenario; `i` approaches zero

Comment: `\b` is [Regular Expression for word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), which means it will split on each word.  It would be similar to using `split(" ")` but has the added benefit of including the spaces

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`String.split()` splits a String based on a regular expression.

`\b` is a regex expression and denotes a word boundary i.e. start of line, end of line, a space, punctuation marks etc. It's passed as `\\b` because Java needs the `\` escaped with another `\`.

When you split() with `""` you're basically splitting on nothing and hence the input string gets broken into individual letters in an array which then gets iterated in reverse and hence you get a string with all of its letters (instead of words) reversed.

Just to elaborate on @LuiggiMendoza's observations

```
i --> 0 // gets interpreted as
i-- > 0 // i.e. it uses a post-fix decrement operator
```

which means the value of `i` gets comapred to `0` first and then the `i = i - 1` happens.

Also, notice the use of `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer` (thread-safe but slow) or plain `String` concatenation (would have created too many unnecessary strings in the Java *string pool*).

Comment: Don't forget to add my comment as part of your answer.